# PHP Customization: Taxonomies and Queries, why?

Tags: php, theme-development, taxonomy

I am new to custom theme development.

What are taxonomies and Queries in Wordpress development? Why are they used in Wordpress?

Answer (score 2):

> Before you start theme development, I suggest you familiarize yourself with general [WordPress Usage](https://codex.wordpress.org/Getting_Started_with_WordPress) & [Terminologies](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Semantics).

## Taxonomy:

In general `taxonomy` means `classification`.

In WordPress, `posts`, `pages`, `custom post types` etc. can be further classified by using different [`taxonomies`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies). For example, you may have hundreds of blog posts. Now how do you classify them for better arrangement? You use `category`, `tags` to do that. So `tags`, `categories` etc. are WordPress defined `taxonomies`.

It's also possible to define [`custom taxonomy`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies#Custom_Taxonomies) [using CODE](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomies/working-with-custom-taxonomies/) or [existing plugins](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/custom-taxonomy). What you do with it depends on your needs.

For example, you write about **movies** in your website (among other things). Now, instead of classifying movies based on WordPress defined `categories` and `tags`, you may create a your own `taxonomy` called [`genre`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Film_genre). Since one movie may fall under multiple `genre`, you can create it so that it behaves like `tags`.

Now if a visitor to your site wants to see all posts from say `action` genre, she'll be able to do so simply by selecting that genre. As a theme developer, you may [provide custom templates](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/taxonomy-templates/) for `genre` taxonomy so that users may get appropriate look and feel that goes well with a movie genre.

## Query:

Every dynamic website needs database & as a developer, sometimes you'll have to get information from the database to show to the users. In WordPress [`Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Query_Overview) simply means asking specific information from the database.

For the most basic information gathering from theme templates, WordPress has a default way of getting data as needed, this is called [the loop](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/). In the loop, WordPress does the database query internally so that you may present related data in templates using simple functions, called [template tags](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-tags/).

However, if you need more information from the database than WordPress provides by default, then you'll have to use [custom query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Queries) to get that.

## Further Reading:

Once you've familiarized yourself with WordPress terminologies and features (as provided in the beginning), I suggest you study [The Official WordPress Theme Development Guide](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/).

Comment: "..you may create a your own taxonomy called genre.."

In response to the above, what's the difference between just making a category named genre simply through the Wordpress Dashboard vs making your own taxonomy? (I'm guessing here... based on necessary customization for the client's needs?) If that gets answered by the The Official WordPress Theme Development Guide, just refer me there.

"..you may provide custom templates for genre taxonomy ."

But, isn't this bad because now users have to update this part, which can eventually break over time? I have someone who had this happen befor

Comment: When you have a category named `genre`, you can assign a `movie` to a `genre` category. That's it. However, when you'll need different `genre` for different `movies`, like one movie is from `action` genre, another from `thriller` genre, how can you do that with just a category named `genre`? That's why you need a custom taxonomy named `genre` & under `genre` taxonomy, you'll have multiple genre named `action`, `adventure`, `romance` etc.

Comment: `"But, isn't this bad because now users have to update this part, which can eventually break over time?"` -- no it'll not break. Every theme is different, so not all theme will support everything. But to make sure you can update the original theme, you'll have to create a child theme and add the custom template in the child theme. That way update to the original theme will not break your site. Read more about child theme: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/